# Configure asset-pipeline to not include resources multiple times (grails 2)?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-2.5

We're in the process of upgrading from grails 2.5 to 3, as a starting point, we're migrating resources to asset-pipeline.  I've read through the docs superficially, but in testing ran into a scenario that's causing problems...  resources are getting included multiple times on the page.

The problem is best illustrated by exampe.  Create `testing.js` file in assets/javascripts:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   alert("test alert");
});
```

In `application.js` (included in main.gsp layout) add `//= require testing`.  On any page in application add `<asset:javascript src='testing'/>`.  Launch the page and the alert shows twice.

**Is there a way to configure asset-pipeline so as not to do this?**

I assume I'm missing something, because this seems like a big problem with transitive dependencies from plugins (e.g., everything depends on jquery).

Adding `grails.assets.bundle=true` to `Config.groovy` doesn't seem to help.

Edit: Adding clarification with jquery example

Our application's application.js contains, among many other things: `//= require jquery-version.js`

Plugins we use provide GSPs that also include jquery-version.js (either in their own asset tag or transitively through included js files) because those pages require jquery to be on the page.  Perhaps I have some fundamental misunderstanding, but this seems correct...  the plugin GSPs should require their dependencies.

Now, on this page, jquery.js is included multiple times.  This seems like a step back from Resources which would resolve multiple inclusions through transitive modules.

Comment: but why would you add to it any page ? it is already added to application.js which means included for all pages. in short exclude it from the application.js ensure tree is not enabled / on within application.js then load on each page you need once

Comment: The test case just demonstrates the problem.  We have files that are needed on every page of the application which are included in the application.js file.  Imagine testing.js is a file from a library.  And some-plugin has a script that also requires testing.js.  We want some-plugin.js on a limited number of pages, but now testing.js is on that page twice.

Comment: Sorry removed to add it again only more clearer, in short please try to explain how your plugin is being accessed by your main application. Is it loading pages from plugin that also call same js? Could the plugin be improved to display specific content as a tagLib call within main site that then re-use the existing js structure of local site.

Comment: Yes, the application requires module.js (genericized name) on every page.  The application includes 3rd party plugins with additional functionality that also requires module.js.  Any page that uses the 3rd party plugin's functionality now has module.js included twice on the page.

Comment: `3rd party plugins with additional functionality that also requires module.js` have you contacted 3rd party about this issue ? it is hard to comment since you are having an issue but expressing it in a very disclosed way. For whatever reason the 3rd party plugin requires usage of the same module you have locally in your app and you are facing this issue. Perhaps the answer is to separate out this local module.js and have a version for plugin and one for local which won't conflict.  Either way a plugin loads over existing site content and shouldn't therefore need you to pass module.js typically

Comment: Edited problem description with clearer actual example with jquery (since comments have limited formatting).

Comment: Possibly a step backwards when looking at it from the way resources configured dependencies. Many ways you can turn this coin though. It could be said that the plugin lacks fluidity to allow template calls to same functions and additional configuration to exclude plugin default css/js files. I haven't been involved with assets plugin. Maybe you could raise it as a concern on their plugin page although i doubt you will get an inclusive fixture to this problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, guess we just need to completely refactor resources and possibly plugins

Comment: if you are coming from resources you will need to change quite a bit tbh so yes whilst you are doing that think of designing either tagLibs that do same functionality but bypass the actual views and render templates. This also means separating content of what is view and rendering the good bit as templates. I used this to help doing some migration work - you can use it to trace old calls https://github.com/vahidhedayati/documentation/blob/master/grails/shellscripts/parse-js-css.sh